# Java 8 code reading

Tags: java, java-8

This piece of Java code is hard to understand. How does this DirExplorer get created? Class DirExplorer link is https://github.com/ftomassetti/analyze-java-code-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/me/tomassetti/support/DirExplorer.java
Cheers,
Code is below:

```
 new DirExplorer((level, path, file) -> path.endsWith(".java"), (level, path, file) -> {
        System.out.println(path);
        System.out.println(Strings.repeat("=", path.length()));
        try {
            new VoidVisitorAdapter<Object>() {
                @Override
                public void visit(ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration n, Object arg) {
                    super.visit(n, arg);
                    System.out.println(" * " + n.getName());
                }
            }.visit(JavaParser.parse(file), null);
            System.out.println(); // empty line
        } catch (ParseException | IOException e) {
            new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }).explore(projectDir);
```

Comment: *"How does this DirExplorer get created?"* -- I don't understand the question. It gets created because you call its constructor. You know, `new DirExplorer(...)`.

Comment: what parameters are behind?

Comment: "Are behind"? You mean what parameters are passed? If so, the answer is the two lambda expressions given.

Comment: I mean, since you've titled the question as "Java 8", I presume you know about Java 8's lambda expressions and how they work. If that is so, then what is unclear about the code?

Comment: It might help if it were refactored a bit: `Filter filter = [first lambda]; Filehandler filehander = [second lambda]; new DirExplorer(filter, filehandler).explore(projectDir);`  If it were written that way, would you understand it, or is there still a part you don't understand?

Comment: [first lambda] means it pretends to be a class implementing filter, in the way that it calls a function which pretends to be the only function of the interface?

Comment: Pretty much--that's what a lambda is.  I wouldn't call it "pretending".  A lambda creates an anonymous class that implements `Filter`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's refactor the code to the old-style for easier understanding:

```
Filter filter = new Filter() {
    @Override
    public boolean interested(int level, String path, File file) {
        return path.endsWith(".java");
    }
};

FileHandler fileHandler = new FileHandler() {
    @Override
    public void handle(int level, String path, File file) {
        // Your long implementation for FileHandler
    }
};
new DirExplorer(filter, fileHandler).explore(projectDir);
```

The variable `filter` is an instance of an anonymous class implementing interface `Filter`, the interface `Filter` has only one method so in Java 8 it's a [functional interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html), and the initialisation code above can be shortened by [lambda expression in Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) to:

```
Filter filter = (level, path, file) -> path.endsWith(".java");

FileHandler fileHandler = (level, path, file) -> {
    // Your implementation for FileHandler
};
new DirExplorer(filter, fileHandler).explore(projectDir);
```

And further more, you could inline both variables, which leads the code to be:

```
new DirExplorer((level, path, file) -> path.endsWith(".java"), (level1, path1, file1) -> {
        // Your implementation for FileHandler
    }).explore(projectDir);
```

Comment: Good comprehensive explanation. Up voted it.

Answer (score 1):

When it's hard to read I break it into smaller, more readable pieces. 
Is this easier to understand ?

```
    Filter filter  = (level, path, file) -> path.endsWith(".java");
    FileHandler fileHandler = (level, path, file) -> {

        System.out.println(path);
        System.out.println(Strings.repeat("=", path.length()));
        try {
            new VoidVisitorAdapter<Object>() {
                @Override
                public void visit(ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration n, Object arg) {
                    super.visit(n, arg);
                    System.out.println(" * " + n.getName());
                }
            }.visit(JavaParser.parse(file), null);
            System.out.println(); // empty line
        } catch (ParseException | IOException e) {
            new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    };

    new DirExplorer(filter, fileHandler).explore(projectDir);
```